# Testing html 5 application cache in GWT hosted mode

Tags: html, gwt, application-cache, gwt-hosted-mode

I'm going to start writing a GWT app with offline capability. In order to use html 5's application cache function, the web server must return a "filetype: text/manifext" header with the manifest file. Does anyone know how I return this header in GWT hosted mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using embedded Jetty server, just create a Filter which will intercept requests to the manifest file, and will add a new header. Or you can use a servlet to generate a manifest file. Or you can use -noserver flag, and setup headers according to your server documentation. 
There are a lot of ways.